# cannot delete file because it's being used by another process

Tags: c#, process, using

I'm getting the error message at the end, when I try to delete files in the "foreach" loop.

I know I need to be using the keyword ´using` somewhere but I'm not sure where and how.

```
private void btnEmailIntegrationFiles_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult EmailWarningMsg = MessageBox.Show("You're about to email the Integration IAT text files. Are you sure?", "WARNING!", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button2);

    if (EmailWarningMsg == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        if (Directory.GetFiles(AppVars.NetworkIntegrationFileLocation).Length == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The folder is empty. Please create the files before sending it.", "Error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        else
        {
            if (Directory.GetFiles(AppVars.NetworkIntegrationFileLocation).Length != 4)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("The folder does not contain exactly 4 files.", "Error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            else
            {
                Email email = new Email();

                email.SendEmailToFinalDestinationWithAttachments(AppVars.DBTeamEmail, AppVars.ChrisWhitmoreEmail, AppVars.DBTeamEmail, "Integration Files", "Please see integration files attached.");
            }
        }

        PopulateListViewWithPoliciesAvailableToHoldBack();

        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(AppVars.NetworkIntegrationFileLocation);

        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            File.Delete(file);
        }
    }
}
```

How would I go about using the keyword `using` for "emailing" so that I don't run into this error message when trying to delete those files that were emailed as attachments?

Here's the send email class:

```
public void SendEmailToFinalDestinationWithAttachments(string EmailFrom, string EmailTo, string EmailCC, string EmailSubject, string EmailBody)
        {
            try
            {
                MailMessage EmailMessage = new MailMessage();
                SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient(AppVars.SMTPClient, AppVars.SMTPClientPort);
                smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                EmailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
                EmailMessage.To.Add(EmailTo);
                EmailMessage.CC.Add(EmailCC);
                EmailMessage.CC.Add(user);
                EmailMessage.Subject = EmailSubject;
                EmailMessage.From = new MailAddress(EmailFrom);
                EmailMessage.Body = EmailBody;

                string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(AppVars.NetworkIntegrationFileLocation, "*" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + "*");

                foreach (string file in files)
                {
                    EmailMessage.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(file));
                }

                smtp.Send(EmailMessage);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Probably on Email; but, you haven't provide any detail about this class.  Where is it from?  What does SendEmailToFinalDestinationWithAttachments do, etc.?

Comment: Clean up the code / refactor it and make sure that you post all necessary code that fits your question.

Comment: email class provided. I'm pretty sure the issue is with "string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(AppVars.NetworkIntegrationFileLocation, "*" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + "*");

                foreach (string file in files)
                {
                    EmailMessage.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(file));
                }" ...how would I go about using the keyword "using" here?

Comment: It's not the cause of your problem but why in the world do you keep redoing the directory read?  The last one is actually dangerous--if something else gets dumped in there in the middle it will be blindly killed.

Comment: you're right. i should be deleting only the files that are supposed to be expected there... though nothing else should be in that folder...

Comment: @LorenPechtel, I'm reading the directory multiple times in order to display the correct error messages to the user. How would I go about checking whether there are no files or there are not exactly 4 files in the folder and notify the user of each issue?

Comment: @user1336632:  It's simply returning an array of strings.  Store it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to modify your EMail class to be something like:

```
using (MailMessage EmailMessage = new MailMessage()) {
    ...
    smtp.Send(EmailMessage);
}
```